# How to re-link Google Play App ? Application is incorrectly configured

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I am receiving well known error:

> The Application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name
>   and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer
>   Console.

I have tried **TOP 3 answers on StackOverflow** regarding this issue, **none worked:**

1. Deleting Credentials from Developer Console
2. Unpublish App and Add another Linked App in Google Play Console

I have changed the *package name of my Game* and then tried to Link it with OAuth 2.0 from Google Play Console. But it seems it generated the same SHA1 fingerprint, as I can still see both (the old package name and new package name) in my **Linked Application**.

And if I publish one, the other one is also automatically published and vice-versa for unpublish. It seems both Apps (with different package names) are linked together. Since the **APPLICATION_ID** provided by OAuth Client is  **always the same.**

What should I try to do ?

I am gladly posting any Screens and / or more information regarding my issue, if you need it.

**SCREEN OF GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE:**
[image: Debugg Screen]